# How to use jq to fetch attribute from json

Tags: shell, unix, jq

I have written a bash file to fetch an attribute value from a json. But it says data not shown. Not sure how to make jq work in my linux box. Can some one please help.

```
 curl -v -H "Content-Type: application/json"  -X GET  'URL'  > myFile.json
 
    cat myFile.json | jq '.offerVerticalMap["GROCERIES.offerPublishStatus"]'
```

in myFile.json the json is getting created but am unable to pull the attribute value.

please can someone look into this at the earliest?

Thanks

Comment: Please share a sample of `myFile.json`.

Comment: provided the json @Mayank Porwal

Comment: Your json seems to be invalid. Please send a proper one.

Comment: @MayankPorwal can u advice now?

Comment: @user3222718 - Your snippet is still not valid JSON.  To check the validity of myFile.json, you can use an online service such as jsonlint.com, or run: `jq empty myFile.json`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json still shows as invalid. Anyhow, I'm attaching a sample json and how to extract it through `jq`. Please see below:

```
~$ cat n1.json
[  
   {  
      "name":"sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-aa",
      "hash":"010d126f8ccf199f3cd5f468a90d5ae1",
      "bytes":4294967296,
      "last_modified":"2018-10-10T01:32:00.069000",
      "content_type":"binary/octet-stream"
   },
   {  
      "name":"sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-ab",
      "hash":"49a6f22068228f51488559c096aa06ce",
      "bytes":397973601,
      "last_modified":"2018-10-10T01:32:22.395000",
      "content_type":"binary/octet-stream"
   },
   {  
      "name":"sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-ac",
      "hash":"2c5e845f46357e203214592332774f4c",
      "bytes":5179281858,
      "last_modified":"2018-10-11T08:20:11.566000",
      "content_type":"binary/octet-stream"
   }
]
```

And then used jq to find the names:

```
~$ jq -r '.[].name' n1.json
sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-aa
sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-ab
sandboxserver.tar.gz.part-ac
```

Let me know if this helps.